# Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a < Provider >

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux'


function rootReducer(state = { name: 'store' }, action) {
    return state
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

function IamUsingStore() {
    const name = useSelector((state) => state.name)
    return <h1>{name}</h1>
}

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <MyProvider store="Store">
                </MyProvider>
                <IamUsingStore />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

If I do not wrap the component with the Provider component I got this error:- **Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a < Provider >**.
Now the question is that how it is validating that a component is wrapped or not?
Anyone can explain with a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Props:

store (Redux Store) The single Redux store in your application.

children (ReactElement) The root of your component hierarchy.

context You may provide a context instance. If you do so, you will need to provide the same context instance to all of your connected components as well. Failure to provide the correct context results in runtime error:

how it is validating that a component is wrapped or not?

The  component makes the Redux store available to any nested components that need to access the Redux store.

Since any React component in a React Redux app can be connected to the store, most applications will render a  at the top level, with the entire app’s component tree inside of it.

> Provider not validate if your component is wrapped or not, he will
> validate if Provider has a Nested Component.

https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

```js
<MyProvider store="Store">
  <IamUsingStore /> // <--- Must be Wrapped by MyProvider
</MyProvider>
```